# Why does this .glb export always have flipped normals?

Tags: export

I've encountered this very strange issue when trying to export to the .glb format. When I attempt to do so, all of my normals are flipped.

[image: The .glb file in 3D Viewer. The normals appear flipped.]

Here's what the .blend file looks like:

[image: The .blend file, illustrating that the normals are facing the right direction.]

I have backface culling enabled, so I know my normals are facing the right direction.

[image: The viewport shading settings, with backface culling enabled.]

Even after flipping the normals to make them face the wrong direction in the .blend file, the normals still appear flipped in the .glb file.

You can find the project files [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1RWDUT8QssAQ5tPNfUe6fOTxflxGikZAS/view?usp=sharing)!

**Edit:** Upon further investigation, I've found that the issue isn't that the normals are flipped, it's that the material makes them appear so. Here it is in 3D Viewer without the texture data:

[image: The model viewed without texture data.]

Why is this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Blend Mode is set to <kbd>Alpha Hashed</kbd>.
To workaround this problem, separate your glasses material and your main texture material, allowing alpha for one material and no alpha for the other.

[image]

## Before:

[image]

## After:

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much! To add onto this, I've found that setting the blend and shadow modes to "alpha clip" allows me to retain the transparency of the glasses while keeping everything in one material.